# Split text into multiple nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, split, cards

I'm creating a card game and I want to generate the cards through TeX.
Here's a minimal version of the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, oneside]{article}


%===========================================================================
% Libs
%===========================================================================

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

%===========================================================================
% Definitions
%===========================================================================
\def\ShapeCardFront{(0.0,0.0) rectangle (6.0,9.7)}
\def\ShapeCardBack{(6.0,0.0) rectangle (12.0,9.7)}
\def\ShapeFrontDescriptionII{(0.2,1.0) rectangle (5.8,7.0)}
\def\ShapeBackDescription{(6.1,0.1) rectangle (11.9,9.6)}

\tikzset{
    CardCorners/.style={
        rounded corners=0.2cm
    },
    ElementCorners/.style={
        rounded corners=0.1cm
    },
}

\newcommand{\CardFrontBorder}{
    \draw[black,CardCorners] \ShapeCardFront;
}

\newcommand{\CardBackBorder}{
    \draw[black,CardCorners] \ShapeCardBack;
}


\newcommand{\CardTypeII}[2]{
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[CardCorners] \ShapeCardFront;
        \fill[ElementCorners, white, opacity=0.95] \ShapeFrontDescriptionII;
        \draw[ElementCorners, color=#1, line width=2] \ShapeFrontDescriptionII;
    \end{scope}
    \node[right] at (0.1,0.5) {\textcolor{white}{\uppercase{\textbf{#2}}}};
    \fill[CardCorners, color=#1] \ShapeCardBack;
    \fill[CardCorners, white] \ShapeBackDescription;
}

\newcommand{\CardContent}[1]{
    \node[below] at (3.0,7.0) {
    \begin{varwidth}{5.4cm}
      \small #1
    \end{varwidth}
    };
}

\newcommand{\CardBackContent}[1]{
    \node[below] at (9.0,9.55) {
    \begin{varwidth}{5.6cm}
      \small #1
    \end{varwidth}
    };
}

\newcommand{\CardTypeCharacter}{\CardTypeII{characterbg}{Monster}}
\definecolor{characterbg}{RGB}{200,050,050}


%===========================================================================
% Document
%===========================================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\CardTypeCharacter
\CardContent{\Huge Block A \\ \scriptsize \lipsum[1]}
\CardBackContent{\Huge Block B}
\CardFrontBorder
\CardBackBorder
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here's what I obtain:

[image]

Now I wonder if is it possible to split the text into the two red boxes (that I've called respectively block A and block B).
In particular I want to fill the block B when the text exceeds from the block A (without doing it manually).

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Is the content of Block A always only text in `\small`, without graphics or tables etc? In that case you could make a conservative estimate of the number of characters that fits in Block A, and split the text based on this number using a string manipulation package (with some provisions not to split mid-word).

Comment: Sometimes I use different font size (\footnotesize or \scriptsize) or tables.

Comment: I don't know the developing stage of your card game format, but may be you could consider `poster` library from `tcolorbox` as an alternative solution to `TikZ`. With your example, each card (front and back) could be a `poster` box where text flows from first to second fragment. Overlay and Underlay elements can be used to introduce decorations to the cards.

Comment: I'm in the final stage now (the card template, thanks to you, is already done now). But if poster is a better solution I could recreate the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`magazine` library from `tcolorbox` can help you. This library can be used to break a long text in fixed length fragments. These fragments are stored into an array and can be printed when needed even in different order.

In this particular case, we need to build `CardContents` with a `magazine-tcolorbox` with a known size (5.4cm width and 5.8cm height for the first fragment). When card contents is longer than 5.8cm, it will break into two fragments, the first is used in `\CardFrontContent` and the second one in `\CardBackContent`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, oneside]{article}


%===========================================================================
% Libs
%===========================================================================

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage{graphicx}  %<-- TikZ already loads graphicx and xcolor
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

%\usepackage{varwidth}

%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{CardContent}{enhanced jigsaw, width=5.4cm, blankest, 
breakable, break at=5.8cm, reset box array, store to box array}

%===========================================================================
% Definitions
%===========================================================================
\def\ShapeCardFront{(0.0,0.0) rectangle (6.0,9.7)}
\def\ShapeCardBack{(6.0,0.0) rectangle (12.0,9.7)}
\def\ShapeFrontDescriptionII{(0.2,1.0) rectangle (5.8,7.0)}
\def\ShapeBackDescription{(6.1,0.1) rectangle (11.9,9.6)}

\tikzset{
    CardCorners/.style={
        rounded corners=0.2cm
    },
    ElementCorners/.style={
        rounded corners=0.1cm
    },
}

\newcommand{\CardFrontBorder}{
    \draw[black,CardCorners] \ShapeCardFront;
}

\newcommand{\CardBackBorder}{
    \draw[black,CardCorners] \ShapeCardBack;
}


\newcommand{\CardTypeII}[2]{
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[CardCorners] \ShapeCardFront;
        \fill[ElementCorners, white, opacity=0.95] \ShapeFrontDescriptionII;
        \draw[ElementCorners, color=#1, line width=2] \ShapeFrontDescriptionII;
    \end{scope}
    \node[right] at (0.1,0.5) {\textcolor{white}{\uppercase{\textbf{#2}}}};
    \fill[CardCorners, color=#1] \ShapeCardBack;
    \fill[CardCorners, white] \ShapeBackDescription;
}

%\newcommand{\CardContent}[1]{
%    \node[below] at (3.0,7.0) {
%    \begin{varwidth}{5.4cm}
%      \small #1
%    \end{varwidth}
%    };
%}
%
%\newcommand{\CardBackContent}[1]{
%    \node[below] at (9.0,9.55) {
%    \begin{varwidth}{5.6cm}
%      \small #1
%    \end{varwidth}
%    };
%}

\newcommand{\CardFrontContent}{
    \node[below] at (3.0,7.0) {
    \useboxarray{1}
    };
}

\newcommand{\CardBackContent}{
    \node[below] at (9.0,9.55) {
    \useboxarray{2}
    };
}

\newcommand{\CardTypeCharacter}{\CardTypeII{characterbg}{Monster}}
\definecolor{characterbg}{RGB}{200,050,050}


%===========================================================================
% Document
%===========================================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{CardContent}
\Huge Block A \\ \scriptsize \lipsum[1]\end{CardContent}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\CardTypeCharacter
\CardFrontContent
\CardBackContent
\CardFrontBorder
\CardBackBorder
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have gotten an answer that fits your needs, but I would still like to add some thoughts and a suggestion. I apologize if this is not the type of solution you look for.

**The main point in writing this answer is to suggest that you put your front side and back side of the cards into ordinary *separate pages*.**

I don't know how to achieve that easily in LaTeX. Probably, one could use some simple document class like `standalone` and the `geometry` package to set the correct dimensions, and finally `tikz` for the overlays. The larger text could be headers.

It is also not clear to me from your question if you need very flexible solutions or not for other cards. In any case, I tried to produce something with ConTeXt, which I know better (but not optimally, so one could think of simplicifations) how to configure. The result is given below (observe that this is a screen shot of the two pages side-by-side)

[image: Cards with ConTeXt]

The code to generate the document above is given below (I did not look too closely at your code, so the dimensions I use differ from yours):

```
% Define and setup the card size
\definepapersize[card][width=160bp,height=240bp]
\setuppapersize[card]

% Define the layout for odd (=left in the picture) pages
\definelayout[odd][
backspace=16bp,
margin=0bp,
edge=0bp,
topspace=80bp,
top=32bp,
topdistance=32bp,
width=128bp,
header=24bp,
headerdistance=8bp,
footer=0bp,
bottom=0bp,
height=fit,
]

% Define the layout for even (=right in the picture) pages
\definelayout[even][
backspace=16bp,
margin=0bp,
edge=0bp,
topspace=16bp,
width=128bp,
header=24bp,
headerdistance=8bp,
footer=0bp,
bottom=0bp,
bottomspace=0bp,
height=fit,
]

% This is needed to 
% 1) make the document doublesided and 
% 2) prevent the page number from showing
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,state=stop]

% Set the style of the header
\setupheader[style={\definedfont[Serif at 20bp]}]
% Set the content of the header
\setupheadertexts[\doifrightpageelse{Block A}{Block B}]

% Set some font parameters. They are not
% really necessary, but anyways
\setuptolerance[stretch]
\setupalign[hz,hanging,line,nothyphenated]
\definefontfeature[default][default][protrusion=quality,expansion=quality,onum=yes]
\definebodyfontenvironment[6bp][interlinespace=8bp]
\setupbodyfont[termes,6pt]

% Define the frame for the odd page
\startuseMPgraphic{cardframeodd}
path p,q;
p = unitsquare xyscaled(OverlayWidth,OverlayHeight) cornered 0.4cm;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 1bp;
q = unitsquare xyscaled(OverlayWidth-16bp,OverlayHeight-72bp) shifted (8bp,8bp) cornered 0.4cm;
draw q withpen pencircle scaled 2bp withcolor darkred;
clip currentpicture to p;
\stopuseMPgraphic

% Put the MetaPost in an overlay
\defineoverlay[cardframeodd][\useMPgraphic{cardframeodd}]

% Set the overlay on "rightpage" (which is odd page, shown to the left in the picture)
\setupbackgrounds[rightpage][paper][background=cardframeodd]

% Below the frame for the even page is setup similarly
\startuseMPgraphic{cardframeeven}
path p;
p = unitsquare xyscaled(OverlayWidth,OverlayHeight) cornered 0.4cm;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 4bp withcolor darkred;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 1bp;
clip currentpicture to p;
\stopuseMPgraphic
\defineoverlay[cardframeeven][\useMPgraphic{cardframeeven}]
\setupbackgrounds[leftpage][paper][background=cardframeeven]


\starttext
% Just put some text into the document
\dorecurse{4}{\input ward\par}
\stoptext
```