# Custom format with multiple textboxes

Tags: fontsize, tcolorbox

I'm trying to make a custom format in which there are several text components in different places of the page, each with a different font and size.
I found this reference: [Insert text into a fixed size box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144299/insert-text-into-a-fixed-size-box), which is helping me create fixed sized boxes, but I encountered two obstacles.
First, The text does not "grow" past a certain value, only shrinks.
Second, it's not easy at all to place the position of each box.
If anyone has any idea to work around this, I appreciate a lot.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a concrete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and illustrates your point.

Comment: `tcolorbox` also offers a `magazine` library which allows to break a text in several boxes and place them independently even in different pages and `poster` library which allows you to compound several boxes over the same page. As initial reference you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384913/1952 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387491/1952 but you'll find some more on this place.

Comment: See also de `flowfram` package.